# MySQL: how to create a record that can be queried for matching patterns

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

I have a phonebook database like this:

```
         company_name |  company_number  |   company_priority
```

Everytime a call comes in, a module in the Asterisk system runs a query against the number to detect what the priority is.

```
select company_priority from clients where company_number like '%NUMBER%';
```

And depending on the priority it routes the calls to different routes.

What I am trying to do right now is if there are any special characters that can be put in a record (yes, instead of in the query). like 1800********

Or, can we execute two different queries?Like  "select * from xx || select * from xx";

I can't change the variables or the query, since it is built in to the module. My only other option would be to rip open the module and make some changes there.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here. Are you saying any number starting with "1800" should get a priority value that overrides the company's priority?

Comment: Can you give a positive and a negative example of what you want to happen?  Are you saying that if I call in from 1-804-555-1212, you want to find fuzzy matches to any 1804555*?  or something like that?

Comment: Yes @trickynixon and Joe. I want a record like 1800* against which I can run a query which will pick out any 1800xxxxxxxxx calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, it works! I'm also surprised! Example:

```
create table tmp ( a varchar(20) );

insert into tmp values ('%ahoj%'), ('nazdar%');

select * from tmp where 'nazdar   ahoj' like a;

+---------+
| a       |
+---------+
| %ahoj%  |
| nazdar% |
+---------+
```

So in your case you can fill e.g. `1080%` in the company_number column to identify all numbers beginning with `1080`. And then test particular NUMBER with this query:

```
select company_priority from clients where 'NUMBER' like company_number;
```

Comment: awesome, i never thought of trying it in the other way.